# How do I detect collisions between a particle-based net and a ball?

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, physics, cloth

I've implemented a net using Verlet integration and many points connected with constrains; like [this demo](http://codepen.io/suffick/pen/KrAwx), but in 3D.

I want to implement collision detection between this net and a ball (like in a soccer game), so the net catches the ball.

I've tried checking for collisions between the ball and net points (treating each like a small sphere), and this somewhat affects the net, but the ball passes through the gaps between points easily.

How should I be approaching this?

Comment: the approach using the net points might work, depending on how many points your net is using - if the ball is passing through anyway, either your net is not dense enough or your collision detection is not working properly. A simpler approach however might be to treat the net as a plane (for collision detection) and calculate the point where the ball hits it, where you can then apply a force to move the net

Comment: I'll try that approach soon.